# Custom Script Extension failing on Virtual Scale Set upgrade

Tags: linux, bash, azure, azure-devops, command-line-interface

I have created an Azure virtual scaleset with Linux VMs. I have to run Azure CLI commands via release pipelines on these VMs so I am trying to install a Azure CLI using Custom Extensions so that every time a new VM is up CLI is installed on the VM.
I have created a .sh file with below command on blob storage :

```
curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | sudo bash
```

I ran below command on from the CLI to deploy the custom extension :

```
az vmss extension set --vmss-name <VMSS Name> --resource-group <Resource Group> --name CustomScript --version 2.0 --publisher Microsoft.Azure.Extensions --settings '{"FileUris": ["https://<Blobscriptpath>/preinstallscript.sh"],"commandToExecute": "bash /preinstallscript.sh"}'
```

This command is installing the extension and I can see that on Azure but when I am upgrading the VM instance I am getting below error:

"Failed to upgrade virtual machine instance ''. Error: Multiple VM extensions failed to be provisioned on the VM. Please see the VM extension instance view for other failures. The first extension failed due to the error: VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'CustomScript'. Error message: "Enable failed: failed to get configuration: json validation error: invalid public settings JSON: FileUris: Additional property FileUris is not allowed""

Below are the images from Azure Portal showing the Extension:

[image]

[image]

Please suggest if I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, *Additional property FileUris is not allowed*, you should use `fileUris` instead of `FileUris`. Read the [Property values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-linux#property-values).

[image]

Also, If the blob is not public, you need to provide the storage account name and key to access the blob. For example, you can provide a `.sh` file on the blob storage.

```
#!/bin/bash

curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | sudo bash
```

and deploy the custom extension with CLI.

```
az vmss extension set --vmss-name <VMSS Name> --resource-group <Resource Group> --name CustomScript --version 2.0 --publisher Microsoft.Azure.Extensions --settings '{"fileUris": ["https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/shscripts/preinstallscript.sh"],"commandToExecute": "sh preinstallscript.sh"}'
```

### Edit

After installing the VMSS, you can upgrade the VMSS instance to take this script effect.

[image]